# PowerShell to iterate through all SharePoint Lists

Tags: list, powershell, site-collection

Is it possible to iterate through all the lists in a site collections and create a folder name "Test" using PowerShell?

Fine Regards

Comment: Yes, it's possible.
Where exactly you stuck at?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Should be something like:

```
# get the site collection
$s = get-spsite http://siteurl 

# loop through all site in the site collection, 
# then through all lists / libraries in that site (filtering out everything but actual doc libs 
# (The catalog filter excludes all sharepoint libs like the masterpage catalog etc.
// for each list, add a folder called test to the rootfolder
$s.AllWebs | Foreach-Object { 
  $_.Lists | Where { ($_.BaseType -eq "DocumentLibrary") -and ($_.BaseTemplate -notmatch "Catalog") } | Foreach-Object {
    $_.RootFolder.SubFolders.Add("Test")
    $_.Update()
  }
}

# P.S.  
# not sure if  you need to call the list's update method after adding the folder
# to show folder info, change $_.RootFolder.SubFolders.Add("Test") into
#Write-Host ($_.Title + " - " + $_.BaseType + " - " + $_.BaseTemplate )
```

Comment: I tried it but it doesn't work as expected? Can you test your codde as well?

Comment: Note the "something like" in the answer ;-)? The purpose of this Q&A site is to educate/ learn and find out things on your own (with the provided help of course :-D). You won't learn anything from a completely written script. For now I'll let you of the hook, check the modified answer